# Importing Private Objective-C headers into Swift within same framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, llvm

We currently have a legacy Objective-C framework that we'd like to introduce some Swift components into. However, I can't figure out how to access the Private- and Project-scoped Objective-C files from our Swift files.

We already use an umbrella header and a modulemap file to declare the public headers that should be included in the library's module, and we want to keep these as the only publicly exposed files. However, our new Swift files (within the same framework) need to also access private headers that we don't want to expose.

I've already tried defining a private modulemap file that lists the private headers I want to use, and then specified it with the MODULEMAP_PRIVATE_FILE build setting, but I dont think this does what we want. It appears to introduce a new MyLibrary.Private module which is publicly visible to external targets (such as the unit test target) but is still not available to the Swift files within the framework.

Any suggestions of how this can be accomplished, or experience doing this in other projects would be greatly appreicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problems recently. The case is, that you can do it another way around, just exposing Swift internally to Objective-C. With some manual work, it will allow you to use Objective-C classes inside Swift (internally and within same framework target) **without** actually exposing ObjC to Swift.

The case a bit too complex to paste everything here. I'm adding a link to my article about the topic. That's the general idea:

1. Mimic your ObjectiveC classes with Swift protocols
2. In your swift code use this protocols
3. Expose internally these Swift protocols to Objective-C (manual work needed)
4. Adopt these protocols by ObjC classes
5. Create in Swift and expose in ObjC a factory, that will create instances of these protocols
6. Create in the factory methods, that will allow you to register concrete types, and expose them to ObjC
7. Register ObjC types from Objective-C code in the Swift factory
8. Use the factory to instantiate ObjC classes, without actually exposing ObjC to Swift (hurray ;) )

[Creating Swift framework with private Objective-C members. The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly](https://medium.com/@amichnia_31596/creating-swift-framework-with-private-objective-c-members-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-4d726386644b)

[Github example project](https://github.com/amichnia/Swift-framework-with-private-ObjC-example)

Comment: I also found your article when researching this issue, and even though `modulemap` s seem complex and not very well documented, they still seem much less complex than the solution you proposed.

Comment: @NRitH, in general, you are right, and in the majority of the use-cases, module maps should be considered a proper solution. But please, bear in mind that it is not truly private; your library user can still import the “private” module and see/use some internal methods/classes. My solution and all the hassle with it is to solve this. In my case, my team was working on a framework used to authenticate and authorize, where security and integrity of data were a top priority. All the actions done by the users were legally binding, so we went through a lot of trouble to harden our product.